# Trying to prove Theorem 4.1 from Neilsen and Chuang algebraically

Tags: linear-algebra, pauli-gates, universal-gates

## Background

Theorem 4.1 of Neilsen and Chuang (10th Anniversary Edition) states how a universal single-qubit unitary can be constructed from Y and Z rotations.

> Suppose $U$ is a unitary operation on a single qubit. Then there exist real numbers $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ such that $$U = e^{i \alpha} R_z(\beta) R_y(\gamma) R_z(\delta) $$

I am trying to prove this by deriving an equivalence with a previous result which states that a universal unitary can also be represented as
$$U = \exp(i\alpha) R_{\hat{n}}(\theta)$$ where $\hat{n} = \left(n_x, n_y, n_z\right)$ is a real unit vector and $R_{\hat{n}}(\theta) = \cos{\frac{\theta}{2}} I - i\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}\left(n_x X + n_y Y + n_z Z\right)$

## My Approach

I tried to expand the expression $R_z(\beta) R_y(\gamma) R_z(\delta)$
Let
$$R_z(\beta) R_y(\gamma) R_z(\delta) = \left(\cos{\frac{\beta}{2}}I - i \sin{\frac{\beta}{2}}Z \right)\left(\cos{\frac{\gamma}{2}}I - i \sin{\frac{\gamma}{2}}Y \right)\left(\cos{\frac{\delta}{2}}I - i \sin{\frac{\delta}{2}}Z \right)$$
On expanding and using trigonometric identities as well as identities for Pauli matrices:
$$R_z(\beta) R_y(\gamma) R_z(\delta) = \cos{\frac{\gamma}{2}}\cos{\frac{\beta+\delta}{2}}I - i \left[\sin{\frac{\gamma}{2}}\sin{\frac{\delta-\beta}{2}}X + \sin{\frac{\gamma}{2}}\cos{\frac{\delta-\beta}{2}}Y + \cos{\frac{\gamma}{2}}\sin{\frac{\delta+\beta}{2}}Z \right]$$
I see that this is vaguely similar to the unitary one gets by rotating about an arbitrary unit vector but I cannot find a mapping between the parameters $\beta, \gamma, \delta$ and the parameters $\theta, \hat{n}$ which would allow me to prove that both formulations for a universal unitary are equivalent.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Luckily that part has been done for you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Conversion_to_other_orientation_representations , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Conversion_formulae_between_formalisms . Otherwise you "just" have to solve three nonlinear equations, e.g., $\cos\frac{\theta}{2}=\cos\frac{\gamma}{2}\cos\frac{\beta+\delta}{2}$